# Get unique record by non-primary attribute in ASP.NET Web API

Tags: asp.net-web-api, entity-framework-core

I have a react App with redux and an ASP.NET Web API as back-end. The back-end has a `Tutor` table with `TutorId` column as primary key.

The table has a column named `userId`. I want to get tutor by `userId`. I have created a method

```
async ActionResult GetTutorByUserId()
```

but it  does not fetch the correct tutor.

Here is the action method of my controller:

```
[HttpGet("tutordashboard")]
public async Task<ActionResult <Tutor>> TutorByUserId(int userId)
{
    var tutor = await _context.Tutor
                              .Where(x => x.UserId == userId)                
                              .FirstOrDefaultAsync();

    if (tutor == null)
    {
        return NotFound();
    }

    return tutor;
}
```

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: "_but it does not fetch the correct tutor_" - does it fetch incorrect tutor or no tutor at all?

Comment: thanks @atiyar for interest.incorrect tutor for example if userId is 2. it fectch record with tutorId 2 whose userId is 3.

Comment: How do you call your action?

Comment: @FiazAhmedRanjha Is it a database first or code first scenario? Could you please share the `Tutor` model and any configuration you made for it in the `OnModelCreating()` method.